# wrongly removed wine

Tags: wine

I removed wine from my computer using this command "sudo apt-get purge wine*" and most of my program files were removed too, is there a way I can repair this without necessarily re-installing ubuntu.

Comment: Can you check if `sudo apt-get install wine*` helps?

Comment: That will only reinstall wine, it won't recover any data.

Answer (score 0):

From the direction your tone went in that post, you seem to be attached more to the data you lost from the purge rather than the actual uninstall of wine itself.

Try not to use that PC until you have a second partition or USB drive with adequate space to recover the files to.  Then **[make your way over to here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)** and download TestDisk and/or PhotoRec to recover the files you lost.

**[Here is a step-by-step from their page](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk%3a_undelete_file_for_ext2)**

There are plenty of recovery solutions out there too if this is too intricate for you.  I wish I had more options to offer but I'm sure I won't be the only one answering here for you.

Make sure when you recover those files that you save them to a different drive or partition so they aren't over-written by each other in the process.

Comment: I lost system applications like python and libre apps they are the most important and they are the ones i need to recover so that i can use my computer normally.

Comment: run this real quick and see what happens:  `sudo apt-get install -f -y` and then also try `sudo apt-get upgrade -u`.  I'm going to bed but I'll see how it's going for you in the morning.  Good luck!

Comment: Excellent glad to hear it.  Would you mind accepting the answer for me?